# Showing values from different fields in an array with ternary

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This small piece of code shows the value of different fields of an array.
I'm looking for a way to improve this nested ternary function. An `if statement` solution would be obvious, so I'm wondering if there is something more elegant to solve it.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function getArray(value){
    var showValue = (value.value1 > 0) ? value.value1 :
                        (value.value2 > 0) ? value.value2 :
                            (value.value3 > 0) ? value.value3 : 0;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += value.system + ": "+ showValue + " ";
  }

function myFunction() {
  var array = [
    {system:"Abba", value1:0, value2:1, value3:0},
    {system:"Mars", value1:0, value2:4, value3:0},
    {system:"Nexus", value1:0, value2:0, value3:6},
  ];
  
  array.map(getArray);

}
</script>
```

Output

```
Abba: 1 Mars: 4 Nexus: 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I'm looking for a way to improve this nested ternary function**

They keys to check could be iterated over - e.g.

```js
function getArray(value) {
  var showValue = 0;
  for (let key of ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']) {
    if (value[key] > 0) {
      showValue = value[key];
      break;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += value.system + ": " + showValue + " ";
}

function myFunction() {
  var array = [
    {system:"Abba", value1:0, value2:1, value3:0},
    {system:"Mars", value1:0, value2:4, value3:0},
    {system:"Nexus", value1:0, value2:0, value3:6},
    {system:"Zeroes", value1:0, value2:0, value3:0}
  ];

  array.forEach(getArray);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

And this could be simplified using the array method [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) combined with logical OR - i.e. `||` for a fall-back value using [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#Short-circuit_evaluation) for the case when no values are greater than zero:

```js
function getArray(value){
  //find the key that has a value greater than zero
  const key = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].find(key => value[key] > 0);   
  //return the value that is greater than zero, or else zero in case no value is greater than zero
  const showValue = value[key] || 0;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += value.system + ": "+ showValue + " ";
}

function myFunction() {
  var array = [
    {system:"Abba", value1:0, value2:1, value3:0},
    {system:"Mars", value1:0, value2:4, value3:0},
    {system:"Nexus", value1:0, value2:0, value3:6},
    {system:"Zeroes", value1:0, value2:0, value3:0}
  ];
  
  array.forEach(getArray);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

### Other review points

#### Improper use of `map` method

The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method "*creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array*"<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)</sup>. For this code [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can be used (as it is in the two snippets above) since the return value of each iteration is not used after the callback is executed. `.map()` could be used to return a string for each object and then update the DOM element only once, which would be better for multiple reasons:

- fewer DOM lookups - remember those aren't cheap
- [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can be used to separate each string with a space, without adding an excess space at the end of the output
- the function would only have one responsibility - in-line with the Single Responsibility principle

```js
function getArray(value){
  const key = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].find(key => value[key] > 0);
  const showValue = value[key] || 0;
  return value.system + ": "+ showValue;
}

function myFunction() {
  var array = [
    {system:"Abba", value1:0, value2:1, value3:0},
    {system:"Mars", value1:0, value2:4, value3:0},
    {system:"Nexus", value1:0, value2:0, value3:6},
    {system:"Zeroes", value1:0, value2:0, value3:0}
  ];
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array.map(getArray).join(" ");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

#### Keep HTML and JavaScript separate

The HTML has an `onclick` attribute:

> ```
> <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
> ```

Instead of using that attribute, the event handling can be setup in Javascript - e.g. using `document.addEventListener()`:

```
document.getElementById('checkBtn').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

this would require an *id* attribute be added to the element - e.g.

```
<button type="button" id="checkBtn">Check</button>
```

though other ways to detect it are possible (e.g. class name, elements of `document.forms`, etc. With this separation the JavaScript (logic) can be modified without ever needing to alter the HTML (markup) - especially helpful in larger projects where one person might update HTML and another the JS.